# Powershell read file live and output to speech

Tags: powershell, speech

What i am looking for is to take powershell and read the file content out to the speech synthesis module.

File name for this example will be `read.txt`.

Start of the Speech module:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech

$Narrator1 = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer

$Narrator1.SelectVoice('Microsoft Zira Desktop')

$Narrator1.Rate = 2

$Location = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\read.txt"

$Contents = Get-Content $Location

Get-Content $Location -wait -Tail 2 | where {$Narrator1.Speak($Contents)}
```

This works once. I like to use the `Clear-Content` to wipe the `read.txt` after each initial read and have powershell wait until new line is added to the `read.txt` file then process it again to speak the content.  I believe I can also make it run in the background with `-windowstyle hidden`

Thank you in advanced for any assistance.

Scott

Comment: And what's your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: I cant figure out how to make it stay in a loop read the file content pipe it to speech  then clear it then wait until something new is written to the file for it to do it all over again.

Comment: Note that there's no _loop_ in your code, only `Get-Content -Wait` which will wait indefinitely for new content to be added to the file. `-WindowStyle Hidden` applies to `Start-Process`, but a background job is the better choice (`Start-Job`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a loop is the answer, I would use the FileSystemWatcher to detect when the file has changed. Try this:

```
$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$fsw.Path = "$env:userprofile\Desktop"
$fsw.Filter = 'read.txt'

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName Changed  -Action {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
    $Narrator1 = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
    $Narrator1.SelectVoice('Microsoft Zira Desktop')
    $Narrator1.Rate = 2

    $file = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath

    $Contents = Get-Content $file
    $Narrator1.Speak($Contents)
}
```

Comment: other than closing the session how do you close the objectevent?

Comment: Thank You Dave, I will try this code out tonight. I will let you know either way if I get a Yah or Nay.

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem was that you accidentally used the previously assigned `$Contents` variable in the `where` (`Where-Object`) script block rather than `$_`, the automatic variable representing the *current pipeline object*:

```
Get-Content $Location -Wait -Tail 2 | Where-Object { $Narrator1.Speak($_) }
```

**`Get-Content $Location -Wait` will poll the input file (`$Location` here) every second to check for new content** and pass it through the pipeline (the `-Tail` argument only applies to the *initial* reading of the file; as new lines are added, they are *all* passed through).

**The pipeline will stay alive indefinitely** - until you *delete* the `$Location` file or abort processing.

Since the command is *blocking*, you obviously need another session / process to add content to file `$Location`, such as another PowerShell window or a text editor that has the file open and modifies its content.

You can keep *appending* to the file with `>>`, but that will keep growing it.

**To *discard the file's previous content*, you must indeed use `Clear-Content`**, as you say, which *truncates* the existing file *without recreating it*, and therefore keeps the pipeline alive; e.g.:

```
Clear-Content $Location
'another line to speak' > $Location
```

---

**Caveat**: Special chars. such as `!` and `?` seem to cause silent failure to speak. If anyone knows why, do tell us. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speak?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Speech_Synthesis_SpeechSynthesizer_Speak_System_String_) offer no immediate clues.

---

As for **background operation**:

**With a *background job*, curiously, the `Clear-Content` / `>` combination appears *not* to work**; if anybody knows why, please tell us.

However, **using `>>` - which grows the file - does work.**

The following snippet demonstrates the use of a background job to keep speaking input as it is being added to a specified file (with some delay), until a special end-of-input string is sent:

```
# Determine the input file (on the user's desktop)
$file = Join-Path ([environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')) 'read.txt'

# Initialize the input file.
$null > $file

# Define a special string that acts as the end-of-input marker.
$eofMarker = '[quit]'

# Start the background job (PSv3+ syntax)
$job = Start-Job { 
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech

  $Narrator1 = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer

  $Narrator1.SelectVoice('Microsoft Zira Desktop')

  $Narrator1.Rate = 2

  while ($true) { # A dummy loop we can break out of on receiving the end-of-input marker
    Get-Content $using:file -Wait | Where-Object { 
      if ($_ -eq $using:eofMarker) { break } # End-of-input marker received -> exit the pipeline.
      $Narrator1.Speak($_) 
    }
  }

  # Remove the input file.
  Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath $using:file

}

# Speak 1, 2, ..., 10
1..10 | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose $_
  # !! Inexplicably, using Clear-Content followed by > to keep
  # !! replacing the file content does *not* work with a background task.
  # !! >> - which *appends* to the file - does work, however.
  $_ >> $file
}

# Send the end-of-input marker to make the background job stop reading.
$eofMarker >> $file

# Wait for background processing to finish.
# Note: We'll get here long before the background job has finished speaking.
Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Waiting for processing to finish to cleanup...'
$null = Receive-Job $job -wait -AutoRemoveJob
```